# R - Keras Churn Tutorial - Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : ValueError: No data provided for "dense_1_input"

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio

I have been working through the Keras (Tensorflow) example for Churn Prediction and came across an error with the below line.

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: No data provided for "dense_1_input". Need data for each key in: ['dense_1_input']
```

The error I got was

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: No data provided for "dense_1_input". Need data for each key in: ['dense_1_input']
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The usual way of using this site is to post questions you haven't been able to solve. If you do subsequently solve it yourself, you can answer your own question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I've given you an up-vote for the answer and a downvote for the question because it is in no way clear how this error occurred. Need [MCVE] to be useful. My experience with request for edits to improve questions has been disappointing overall (but please do prove me wrong) , so I'm also voting to close for lack of  [MCVE] to accompany an error-related question.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has the problem it can be solved by changing newdata into as.matrix(newdata)

```
# Setup lime::predict_model() function for keras
predict_model.keras.models.Sequential <- function(x, newdata, type, ...) {
  pred <- predict_proba(object = x, x = as.matrix(newdata))
  data.frame(Yes = pred, No = 1 - pred)
}
```